# How to open ie.exe within an If/Else statement

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a piece of code so when the user clicks "yes" on my message box my yes.gif opens in IE, but if the user clicks "no" I want my no.gif to open in IE. I get a synax error on line 5 (`Else` statement).

My code:

```
Result = MsgBox("Text", 20, "Title")

If Result = vbYes Then Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Else Result = vbNo Then Set objExplorer1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objExplorer
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .Visible = 1
    .Document.Title = "Right Decision"
    .Toolbar = False
    .Statusbar = False
    .Top = 500
    .Left = 500
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 600
    .Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<img src='C:\User\yes.gif'>"
End With

With objExplorer1
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .Visible = 1
    .Document.Title = "Wrong Decision"
    .Toolbar = False
    .Statusbar = False
    .Top = 500
    .Left = 500
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 600
    .Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<img src='C:\User\no.gif'>"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- The only possible values from the `MsgBox` are `vbYes` and `vbNo` because you launched it with the `vbYesNo` flag. Since the result is binary there is no need for multiple comparisons (which don't work like that in VBScript anyway).
- Your `If` statement uses the single-line `If..Then` form, meaning that the subsequent `Else` is invalid. And even if it weren't invalid the syntax would still be incorrect.
- Starting different IE instances is pointless when a string and an image name are the only differences.
- Your code tries to configure both instances, but one of them will be invalid regardless of the user's choice.

Use an `If..Then..Else` to define the settings that actually differ, then create the IE instance after the conditional and configure it accordingly.

```vb
Result = MsgBox("Text", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Title")

If Result = vbyes Then
    title   = "Right Decision"
    picture = "C:\User\yes.gif"
Else
    title   = "Wrong Decision"
    picture = "C:\User\no.gif"
End If

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .Visible   = True
    .Document.Title = title
    .Toolbar   = False
    .Statusbar = False
    .Top       = 500
    .Left      = 500
    .Height    = 400
    .Width     = 600
    .Document.Body.InnerHtml = "<img src='" & picture & "'>"
End With
```